# Is there any cryptography-based assured data deletion technique currently as a standard?

Tags: encryption, public-key, keys, hybrid-encryption

I've recently read part of a book exploring secure data deletion techniques for many storage mediums. In particular, I read about **assured data deletion** techniques developed for data outsourced to the **cloud**. Many of the alternatives are based on cryptographic techniques using symmetric encryption to encrypt data and some sort of asymmetric encryption to encapsulate the symmetric key. I understand the idea is to find a clever way to distribute and destroy the symmetric key to ensure the deletion of data in a remote server.

Is there any standardized technique for assured data deletion in the cloud?

Comment: You don't own the cloud, so theoretically your information is already in the hands of three letter agencies. Anyway, SSD and HDD use different techniques. regardless of being cloud or not! Anyway, see https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/specialpublications/nist.sp.800-88r1.pdf

Comment: @kelalaka I think that Aljndrop is suggesting that the cloud side data is in encrypted form, so even if the 3LAs have it, they can't read it.

Comment: @PaulUszak then there is no need to delete as long as you keep your key secure.

Comment: @kelalaka Hi, thank you for the comment. It is not "deletion" in the strict sense of the word. The goal is to store data in the cloud in encrypted form. Therefore, when the key is deleted, we can request the data deletion from our cloud service provider. Even if the CSP keeps the data, it is useless because the decryption key no longer exists, so it is an assured data deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any standardized technique for assured data deletion in the cloud?

For some definition of standardized, yes: store data encrypted (symmetrically or with hybrid encryption) in the cloud, with decryption by the legitimate user in an environment they trust. Destruction of the data is by destroying the decryption key, and requiring the cloud storage provider to stop billing for the storage. It's then their best interest to destroy the ciphertext, and we do not care if they act otherwise. We are back to a (difficult) problem of key management, with the volume of the data immaterial.

A common name for that is [*Client-Side Encryption Cloud Storage*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Client-Side%20Encryption%20Cloud%20Storage).

---

Many of the other solutions I read about are insecure, or/and detached from reality and standard common sense assumptions. E.g. [this](https://doi.org/10.1109/MNET.011.1900165) article admits

> it is difficult for the cloud server to return a technical proof by which the data owner is convinced that their data are deleted

and instead proposes that

> after the deletion of the data, the cloud server can return a message (“Delete, fname”) and its signature Sig(“Delete, fname”), where fname denotes the file name of the deleted file. The signature can be viewed as a publicly verifiable evidence which indicates that the file has been deleted successfully.

That's undeniably a cryptography-based solution, but it's security rests on the assumptions that the cloud server provider is trustworthy, and that no copy was made of the data, by that provider or otherwise.

The risk of data copy is brushed away by that same article when it discusses storing a file in the cloud, allowing access to multiple users, and then hoping for secure deletion. As long as at least some fraction of users have a computer they control (which I hope is for long), this won't be.

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to considering the cloud as an untrusted party or at best an honest-but-curious party. These techniques are so interesting to me, you helped me a lot.